# Unable to use subversion on OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, apache, svn, ssl, openssl

I've been trying to get subversion to work on my Mac...

Some facts:
1) I configured the subversion with Apache on a Linux server myself and installed a signed SSL cert there as well.

2) On Windows, Tortoisesvn works just fine with my repository.

3) On mac, it doesn't telling me the following error:

> $ svn co https://www.[snip].com/svn/snip .
>
> svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://www.[snip].com/svn/snip'
>
> svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://www.[snip].com/svn/[snip]': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://www.[snip].com)

4) I searched the web and the recommended action is to update the openssl on my machine. I did that and built it locally. Now, when I do 'openssl version', the version that it show is:

> $ openssl version
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012

5) I also installed the subversion client from http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx

6) Both openssl and subversion were put on the path in .bash_profile and I've verified that they are the ones I am using.

The problem is that it is STILL giving the same error message on the Terminal.

Any ideas as to why it works just fine on Windows and doesn't work on the Mac Terminal and most importantly what I should do about it?

Thank you!
-YC.

Comment: Could there be a time difference issue? I know I have had problems with SSL certificates when my system time was out of sync with the server.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL is the Mac client built against? 0.9.x?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the hostname/virtualhost entry does not match the SSL cert.

Comment: How do you test this?